# Sometimes the image in the ImageView does not show

Tags: android, imageview

On an Activity there are 4 views where the user can "bet" on the correct answer for the question, based on the current amount currently on the answer the image with the amount of money changes (from nothing to a single pack of money and up to a pile of money).

Sometimes when the value is added to the View (either by touch/click or by dragging it from another answer) the image does not show (this only happens if there wasn't any money on that answer before).

Here is the View code (I added a couple of logs and comments to it):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SuperMoneyView extends LinearLayout
{
    protected TextView _moneyValueTextView;
    protected ImageView _moneyPacktView;
    protected long _value = 1000000;
    private Activity _activity;
    protected boolean _isSoundActive = false;

    public SuperMoneyView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SuperMoneyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SuperMoneyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initConfig(true);
    }

    public SuperMoneyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initConfig(true);
    }

    public void initConfig(boolean setDefaultValues)
    {
        setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
    }

    public View getMoneyValueView()
    {
        return _moneyValueTextView;
    }

    public void setImage(final Drawable drawable)
    {
        Log.e("AnswerView", "setImage");
        if(drawable == null)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "setImage -- Drawable Null");
            _moneyPacktView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "setImage -- Drawable Not Null");
            _moneyPacktView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if(_moneyPacktView != null)
        {//This part is executed but the image does not show
            Log.e("AnswerView", "setImage -- Real set image");
            _moneyPacktView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            _moneyPacktView.setAlpha(1.0f);
            _moneyPacktView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public ImageView getMoneyImageView()
    {
        return _moneyPacktView;
    }

    public boolean isSoundActive()
    {
        return _isSoundActive;
    }
    public void setSoundActive(boolean active)
    {
        _isSoundActive = active;
    }

    public long getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
    public void setValue(long value)
    {
        setValue(value, _value);
    }
    public void setValue(long value, long oldValue)
    {
        final boolean playSound = value > oldValue;
        _value = value;

        if(_activity == null)
        {//This part is never executed (Activity is always different than null)
            Log.e("AnswerView", "SetValue no Activity");
            realSetValue(playSound);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _activity.runOnUiThread(//I tried this, because I thought that maybe it wasn't running on the UI Thread
                        new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                realSetValue(playSound);
                            }
                        }
                );
                Log.e("AnswerView", "SetValue Activity");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {//Never called either
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("AnswerView", "SetValue Catch");
                realSetValue(playSound);
            }
        }
    }
    private void realSetValue(boolean sound)
    {
        Log.e("AnswerView", "RealSetValue");
        if(_moneyValueTextView != null)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "_moneyValueTextView != null");
            if(sound && isSoundActive())
            {
                Log.e("AnswerView", "Sound Active");
                MediaUtils.playMoneyDrag();
            }
            _moneyValueTextView.setText("" + _value);
        }
        if(_moneyPacktView != null)
        {//Always different than null
            Log.e("AnswerView", "_moneyPacktView != null");
            setImage(getImageForAmount(_value));
        }
    }

    public void updateValue(long toAdd)
    {
        long oldValue = _value;

        _value += toAdd;
        if(_value < 0l)
        {
            _value = 0l;
        }
        setValue(_value, oldValue);
    }

    public void setWrong()
    {
        if(getValue() > 0)
        {
            RemoveMoneyAnimation animation = new RemoveMoneyAnimation(_moneyPacktView);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }

    private Drawable getImageForAmount(long amount)
    {
        if(amount == 0)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- amount == 0 -- Null");
            return null;
        }
        else if(amount <= 50000)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- icn_money_pack_bet_single");
            return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_money_pack_bet_single);
        }
        else if(amount <= 150000)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- icn_money_pack_bet_medium");
            return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_money_pack_bet_medium);
        }
        else if(amount <= 500000)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- icn_money_pack_bet_full");
            return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_money_pack_bet_full);
        }
        else if(amount <= 1000000)
        {
            Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- icn_money_pack_bet_extra_full");
            return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_money_pack_bet_extra_full);
        }
        Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- Null");
        return null;
    }

    protected class RemoveMoneyAnimation extends Animation implements Animation.AnimationListener
    {
        final View _view;
        final float _initialWidth;
        final float _initialHeight;

        public RemoveMoneyAnimation(View view)
        {
            _view = view;
            _initialWidth = _view.getWidth();
            _initialHeight = _view.getHeight();

            setAnimationListener(this);
        }

        public void restoreViewSize()
        {
            _view.getLayoutParams().width = (int)_initialWidth;
            _view.getLayoutParams().height = (int)_initialHeight;
            _view.setLayoutParams(_view.getLayoutParams());
            _view.setRotation(0.0f);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
        {
            try
            {
                if(interpolatedTime > 0.5f)
                {
                    _view.setAlpha(1.0f + (-1.0f * (interpolatedTime - 0.5f) * 2.0f));
                }
                _view.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(_initialWidth - (_initialWidth * interpolatedTime));
                _view.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(_initialHeight - (_initialHeight * interpolatedTime));
                _view.setLayoutParams(_view.getLayoutParams());
                _view.setRotation(0.0f + (360.0f * interpolatedTime * 2.0f));


            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        @Override public boolean willChangeBounds() { return true; }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                _activity.runOnUiThread(
                                        new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                restoreViewSize();
                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                        }
                    },
                    getDuration()
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){

        }
    }
}
```

Basically every time that `setValue` (force the value) or `updateValue` (add or subtract to the current value) is called the method `setImage` is called to set the corresponding image.
Based on the logs I got the following conclusions:

- The `ImageView` size is always different that 0 (on Nexus 5 is fixed at around 312x256)
- The correct image is always selected
- The code is running on the UI Thread
- The `setImageDrawable` is being called with the correct drawable

I ran out of ideas to what may be the problem, anyone has a clue?

**EDIT: Added the code for the extended class and XML code**

This is the `AnswerView` class it extends the `SuperMoneyView` to add the TextView methods

```
public class AnswerView extends MoneyView
{
    TextView _answerTextView;
    LinearLayout _answerBoxLinerLayout;
    RelativeLayout _betBoxContainerRelativeLayout;

    private String _answer = "";

    public AnswerView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AnswerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AnswerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initConfig(true);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AnswerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initConfig(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void initConfig(boolean setDefaultValues)
    {
        super.initConfig(setDefaultValues);

        _answerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
        _moneyValueTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moneyBetTextView);
        _moneyPacktView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.betBoxTextView);
        _answerBoxLinerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerBoxLinerLayout);
        _betBoxContainerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.betBoxContainerRelativeLayout);

        setAnswer(_answer);
        setValue(0l);
    }

    public TextView getTextView()
    {
        return _answerTextView;
    }

    public String getAnswer()
    {
        return _answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer)
    {
        if(answer == null){ answer = ""; }

        _answer = answer;
        if(_answerTextView != null)
        {
            _answerTextView.setText(_answer);
        }
    }

    public void setNormal()
    {
        _answerBoxLinerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_dark_gray_square_blue_border);
        setValue(0l);
        setAlpha(1.0f);
    }
}
```

The class initConfig is called by the activity after the user selects `start` (the layout is already drawn and visible)

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.game.views.game.AnswerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <com.walkme.moneyquiz.views.extended.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
        style="@style/answerTextViewStyle"
        android:text="All at the same time"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/answerBoxLinerLayout"
        style="@style/answerBetBoxStyle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dark_gray_square_blue_border">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/betBoxContainerRelativeLayout"
            style="@style/moneyPackBetRelativeLayoutStyle">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/betBoxTextView"
                style="@style/moneyPackBetImageInRelativeLayoutStyle"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_money_pack_bet_extra_full"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.walkme.moneyquiz.views.extended.AutoResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/moneyBetTextView"
            style="@style/betValueTextStyle"
            android:text="5.000$"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.test.game.views.game.AnswerView>
```

This is added to the main layout using the `include` tag inside a `TableRow` with equal `weight` distribution.

Here are the styles used:

```
<style name="answerTextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/marginSmall</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/marginSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSizeSmall</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/mainBlue</item>
</style>
<style name="answerBetBoxStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/marginSmall</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="moneyPackBetRelativeLayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
<style name="moneyPackBetImageInRelativeLayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/imageHeightMedium</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>
</style>
<style name="betValueTextStyle" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSizeMedium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It's unclear where your set the _moneyPacktView variable. Also, why do you have 2 getter methods for this view? (getImageView & getMoneyImageView). Please post the part of the code which sets this variable. It could be that this view isn't initialised properly.

Comment: I added the requested information to the question, I didn't add the main layout as it has a lot of other stuff and many, many styles. Anyway the views are always different than null and have the correct size (in both cases, when the image shows and when it doesn't), which makes me believe that there isn't a problem with the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the image size after calling the invalidate. If the size is wrong force it to be the correct one.

Comment: Hm.. this was the problem, after the invalidate call the`ImageView` would reset its size to 0 and would not 'grow' back.. but this does not happen every time.. weird..

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from you code,default image for `_moneyPacktView` is not set. When `getImageForAmount()` with 0, null return given and  setImage() with null parameter only set `_moneyPacktView` to visible. Maybe that why your image does not show. Perhaps you might add below code for null parameter in you `setImage()`

```
if(drawable == null)
{
  Log.e("AnswerView", "setImage -- Drawable Null");
  _moneyPacktView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anyDefaultImage));
  _moneyPacktView.setAlpha(1.0f);
  _moneyPacktView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  invalidate();
}
```

or in your `getImageForAmount()`

```
 if(amount == 0)
 {
   Log.e("AnswerView", "getImageForAmount -- amount == 0 -- Null");
   return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anyDefaultImage);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Besides, when the amount is 0 there should not be any image visible. The problem is that 7 out of 10 times it works fine, the other times the image never show, and as soon as the image stops showing, it never shows again until I destroy the activity and return, but according to the logs every thing is working as it should :/